# Unable to select <div> window using selenium webdriver in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I clicked on a link which opens a small window/popup/iframe and the popup window has Xpath:

```
//html/body/div[2]
```

ie. it has no window_id but in firebug the identifier shows the window as a `<div class="some_name">` so I'm assuming it's a popup window; correct me if I'm wrong.

When I use the selectPopup of selenium IDE it works fine in switching from the main window to the popup/new_window but when exporting to webdriver-python it doesn't have that option. So I tried using `driver.switch_to_window` and `switch_to_frame` along with the xpath mentioned above but no luck ie. `driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//html/body/div[2]"))`

Error thrown : `NoSuchElementException` and that's because it's not able to select the iframe.

Since it's working fine in Selenium IDE I exported it to python-webdriver which converted the wait_for_element clause to

`for i in range(60):
     try:
         if self.is_element_present(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='heading']/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[2]/a"): break
         except: pass
         time.sleep(1)  else: self.fail("time out")`
which returns the above error

*Detailed html*: 
 `//*[@id='heading']/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[2]/a` is the xpath of the element and as html this is what it is `<a href="/my_url/test/Home/">Home</a>` and in detail: 
`

```
<div class="help">
<div class="page-header">
<div id="heading">
<div id="search">
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="navbar-inner">
<div class="container">
<ul class="nav">
<li class="active">
<li>
<a href="/my_url/test/Home/">Home</a>
</li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
</ul>
<form class="navbar-form pull-right">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>`
```

Comment: If the window that gets shown is in the same document as the page itself, then it's not a true popup. You may be able to just use `driver.find_element_by_xpath`

Comment: @voithos: I believe it's an iframe so I tried switch_to_frame as well in addition to driver.find_element_by_xpath; both didn't work

Comment: If it's an iframe, then you seen to `find_element_by_xpath` the iframe *itself*, and then you can use `driver.switch_to_frame(iframe_obj)`

Comment: That's exactly what I had done and above is the xpath of the iframe/popup; so the code I tried was: `driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//html/body/div[2]"))` which didn't work

Comment: Does it throw an exception of any kind?

Comment: you read my mind - `NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34088/discussion-between-l-p-and-voithos)

Answer (score -1):

try out this :

```
new Actions(driver).click(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='pop-up-window']"))).perform();
```

Comment: Please use 4 spaces in front of the code to format it as code.